# Передать значение переменной из JS в PHP для использования в скрипте

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

Я пытаюсь передать значение переменной из js в php, используя следующий код по примеру:

```
$(document).on('click', '#editBtn', function(){
    // Здесь код для получения значения ID строки 
    var ID = $(this).closest('tr').find("input.table__text--input[name='ID']").val();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./include/popup/dbselect.php",
        data: {'ID': 'ID'},
        success: function(responseText) {
            console.log(ID);    
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

Значение переменной я нахожу на странице при нажатии на ссылку. Далее это значение я хочу использовать в php запросе, чтобы вывести из бд данные. Я пытаюсь передать его в файл, где содержится скрипт для вывода данных из бд. В консоль выводится правильное значение.
Но оно не передается в php. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: почему ты думаешь что оно не передаётся в PHP?

Comment: "В консоль выводится правильное значение"  --- в какую консоль? какое значение?

Comment: `data: {'ID': 'ID'},` Здесь передается строка. Уберите кавычки, чтобы передавалась переменная.

Comment: Покажи каким образом на сервере проверяешь пришли данные или их нет.

Comment: @AntonMironov без кавычек тоже пробовал, результат один.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я проверяю находится ли правильное значение, выводя его при помощи console.log(ID); в консоль. Оно выводится. Но если я пытаюсь вывести значение переменной в которую передаю значение, то там пусто.   
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    echo $ID;

Comment: @mkorosty при таком раскладе надо `console.log(responseText)` делать.... к тому же, можно посмотреть в консоли вернулось ли что-то от сервера - на вкладке Network в доп. вкладке Ответ (Response).  Ещё можно использовать отладку в PHP чтобы убедиться что приходит ли что-то или нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, если использую console.log(responseText), то выводится нужное значение, а после код из dbselect.php, то есть что должно было выводится из базы в попап на сайте. Например вот так - 1<label class="label">ID</label> <input class="form__input"  placeholder="ID" name = "ID" value="1">

Comment: ты определись с проблемой... в самом вопросе ты пишешь, что *"оно не передается в php"* .... теперь ты пишешь, что *"если использую console.log(responseText), то выводится нужное значение"* ..... если выводится нужное значение, значит оно передаётся в PHP........   итог: твоя проблема не ясна. Тебе нужно переформулировать нормально проблему

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, изначально мне казалось что оно не передается, но проверив как вы написали оказалось что передается, но не выводится на сайт почему-то. Я впервые все это делаю, поэтому возникают трудности

Comment: Придётся оформить новый вопрос с другой проблемой)) где предоставить js html и полностью описать что делаешь и с чем проблема.. сейчас смысла нет что-то обсуждать в комментарии) Т.к. к делу (к текущей проблеме) это уже не относится